# PHP or Blade - Organized Columns depending on the number of data

Tags: php, laravel, menu, count

I'm blocked for organize my sub-menu of my menu. As you can see, 
it is decomposed into several blocks (i've use paint for delimited the block in black).

[image]

currently my code is:

```
<li class="dropdown yamm-fw">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="200">{{ $category->nom }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <div class="yamm-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h5>test</h5>
                            <ul>     
                                <?php $count=0 ?>
                                @foreach ($types->whereIn('id', $category->produit->unique('type_id')->pluck('type_id')) as $type)
                                    @if ($count <= 6)
                                        <li><a href="#">{{$type->nom}}</a></li>
                                        <?php $count++ ?>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach 
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <h5>teste 2</h5>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="category.html">Trainers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="category.html">Sandals</a></li>
                                <li><a href="category.html">Hiking shoes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="category.html">Casual</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

I do not know how to do that after 7 items in the actual div col-sm-3, create another div to continue the foreach and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable):

```
@if ($loop->iteration === 7)
    // Create another div here
@endif
```

Comment: Where i use it ? In foreach ?

Comment: @emeliku yes, inside any loop. Read the docs (click the link in the answer), it has couple of examples which I hope will help you.

Comment: Mmhh.. How to do it if the foreach is in the first div ? Its going to make a div in a div

Comment: @emeliku I'm sorry, but I didn't understand your question from the previous comment.

Comment: If i put the @if loop iteration in my foreach,This will create a div in the 1st div as well as in the ul.